# font awesome icons showing as a blank square

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am not sure why the font awesome shows as an empty square.

```
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <input type="email" class="form-control validate">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Enter your email</label>
        </div>
```

Here's the libraries I used:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XYZ</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/56018e5250.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

[image]

I also tried `fa` and `fas` instead of `fab` and none worked.

here is what I see:
[image]

However, when I try this in jsfiddle I am able to see the email icon. But using the `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` doesn't work either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use the embedded code snippet tool, to help explain what this code does and does not yet do. And what you what you want it to do

Comment: make sure your pc is connected with the internet, coz here your using cdn of fontawesome, so for cdn u need to be connected with the interner

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" 
   integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"> this cdn works. try by this

Comment: @Mona, I think you have fonts related issue. Please check your console, is there any error or warning related to fonts with the extension .ttf, .woff or .woff2?

Comment: What error do you see in browser console.log?

Answer (score 2):

Using this worked

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have:

> <scriptsrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
> **and Also make sure you have class name fa with the icon.
> For e.g  this will not work --> 
> this will work   ---->**

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" class="form-control validate">
        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Enter your email</label>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this, This is working fine
Thanks :)